# Resources for learning tk/tile

Tags: ruby, user-interface, tk-toolkit, tile

Besides Ruby-Doc, what sources are best to take some examples and tutorials from, especially about Tk/Tile in Ruby? I found myself more normal with

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_tk_guide.htm
- http://www.perfectxml.com/syngress/ruby/Page1.asp

but the information is pretty vague, and there is not so much to learn from. I had to consult multiple sources. I found two books from O'Reilly Media:

- http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565924987.do
- http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565924338.do

but don't know if it's the right thing to start with. Even Lynda.com doesn't have anything interesting to look into.

Comment: I highly recommend that you use the QT framework, it's easy and well docummented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best site I know of for learning Tk is [TkDocs](http://www.tkdocs.com/), which has a [tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/index.html) that covers multiple languages including Ruby. (To just see the Ruby version, set the language in the side-bar. Alternatively, leave it at the default of “All Languages” to find out how other languages bind the same library; the differences can be illuminating…)